# How to fix import path in anaconda?

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, anaconda, conda

Conda of my friend stopped to work after intensive attempt to install FEniCS DOLFIN. The Anaconda had been installed in the friend's `$HOME/anaconda` directory (with the directory added to the `$PATH`). Removal of the directory and installation in a new location have not solved the problem:

```
$ conda info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/bin/conda", line 4, in <module>
    import conda.cli
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .main import main  # NOQA
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 46, in <module>
    from ..base.context import context
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ..common.url import urlparse, path_to_url
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/common/url.py", line 17, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.util.url import parse_url
ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3.util.url
```

However `/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/url.py` DOES EXIST.

I have tried to inspect the `sys.path` (both in `ipython` and `python`). The result is:

```
['',
 '/home/user/anaconda2/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

Note the 3rd (`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`) and last (`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions`) element of the list. I suspect it to be the cause of trouble since in `sys.path` of my (working fine) Anaconda there is no reference to `/usr/lib`.

Also other Anaconda tools of my friend seems to be affected:

```
$ ~/anaconda2/bin/pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

I have found similar (unanswered) question [conda missing requests.packages.urllib3.util.url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786546/conda-missing-requests-packages-urllib3-util-url) but it is unclear, what is the content of `sys.path` there.
There is also [How to fix ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440060/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-packages-urllib3) - but Anaconda is not mentioned there.

[EDIT]

The problem is NOT systemwide - at my account I have installed Anaconda succesfully and it works fine. No suspicious entries in `sys.path` too.

[EDIT]

Desperate times call for desperate measures. The problem has been <del>fixed</del>walked arround with removal of friend's home directory.